# How to remove \toprule from top left cell

Tags: booktabs

How can I remove the \toprule above a specific cell?

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l l l}
      \toprule
       & column & column\\
      \midrule 
      row & word & longword\\
       & word & word\\
       & word & word\\
       & word & word\\
       &  & word\\
       &  & word\\
      \midrule 
      row & word & word\\
       & word & word\\
       & word, word & word\\
       & word & word\\
       & word & word\\
       &  & word\\
       &  & word\\
       &  & word\\
      \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `\cmidrule[2-3}` instead. *Unrelated*: don't use  the `center` environment nested in `table`. It adds spurious vertical spacing. Use the `\centering` directive in the place of the environment.

Comment: That should be `\cmidrule{2-3}`. @Bernard that will not have the same thickness and spacing as `\toprule`.

Comment: Maybe you meant `\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-3}` ? Seems to work. @Bernard thank you, that explains some issues!

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of  taking into account the rule thickness.

Comment: Though I'm not 100% sure the spacing above and below are the same, but perhaps it is good enough

Comment: The purpose of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` is to isolate the table from the context; it makes little sense to remove part of them.